# Why does glmnet use coordinate descent for Ridge regression?

Tags: lasso, regularization, ridge-regression, glmnet, elastic-net

If I understand it correctly, glmnet uses cyclical coordinate descent not only for lasso and elastics nets, but also for Ridge regression.

Why does it use this algorithm, which sometimes gives slightly inaccurate results, when there is in fact an easy closed form solution available?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Imagine you have $\lambda_1 \approx \lambda_2$, and you seek $\hat\beta^{ridge}_{\lambda_1}$ and $\hat\beta^{ridge}_{\lambda_2}$, the ridge regression estimates indexed by tuning parameter. To use the closed form to find $\hat\beta_{\lambda_2}$ after computing $\hat\beta_{\lambda_1}$, you'd have to solve a whole different linear system that you used to solve for $\hat\beta_{\lambda_1}$. But, to use coordinate descent with warm starts, you'd very quickly and efficiently find $\hat\beta_{\lambda_2}$.

Comment: iterative methods have some advantages on very large and sparse system. so even in some case, closed form solution available, we still use iterative methods. For example CG for solving linear system

Answer (score 7):

I think this is due to speed. Cyclical coordinate descent does not find the exact solution in finite time, but it is faster, not only for a grid of $\lambda$'s but also for a single $\lambda$.

Consider the task of solving ridge regression for a single $\lambda$, with a data matrix of size $n \times p$. I believe the optimal runtime for exact ridge regression is $O(n^2p)$ if $n < p$ and $O(np^2)$ if $n > p$. See Murphy, *Machine Learning*, section 7.5.2 for a reference.

With the cyclical coordinate descent algorithm, "a complete cycle through all $p$ variables costs $O(pN)$ operations" (p. 6, Friedman et al. 2010, https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v033i01). One can then specify a number of cycles $c$ with $c \ll min(n, p)$ to get a faster big-Oh runtime for a single $\lambda$. For solving over many $\lambda$'s, the `glmnet` method should yield further improvement using warm starts.

Answer (score 1):

Other solvers for ridge exists and the point of the glmnet solver is exactly to use CCD for tractability and speed reasons. They use the same code for *all* elasticnet solutions. Elasticnet includes ridge and LASSO by setting $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ to $0$.